# .htaccess trouble with hiding file extension and forcing trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

When I type domain.com/page.php it doesn't automatically change to domain.com/page/. Also, for the pages in subdirectories, if I follow a link to domain.com/sub/1/ everything is fine, but if I type it in the browser it redirects to domain.com/1/

This is what i have in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas what I should do to htaccess files in the subdirectories and root directory? I'm new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of rules.

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# .php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```