# hide .php extension & force trailing slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to delete the .php extension and force trailing slashes in the end of the URLs.

I've found an answer to do it exactly what I need at ([.htaccess trouble with hiding file extension and forcing trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749033/htaccess-trouble-with-hiding-file-extension-and-forcing-trailing-slash)) but it does not work, I believe it's due to how I am forcing my website to change the document root.

As I do not have access to Virtual Hosts I must change my document root using htaccess, and I have accomplished it by applying the following code..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
```

The only working solution that I've been able to apply to hide the .php extension is with the code below.

### removing .php extension(only working solution)

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

This code is in the thread that I have linked above, but it does not work on my website as I believe it's due to the document root.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# .php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these modified rules with different ordering:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www before hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# if on article page, get slugs and make into friendly url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=302,NE]

# if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

# Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

# allow page direction to change the slugs into friendly seo URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# silently rewrite to webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# .php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response yet again. I am having only one issue as of right now. http://pastebin.com/VN6JpKdb

Comment: Do you this rule also: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)` I didn't see it your question above?

Comment: Yes, I do use it. I didn't realize I didn't add it, I think because I've bothered so much already.

Comment: For some reason it's giving website unavailable when I add the code to .htaccess, so there's something wrong on the redirect part.

Comment: Can you check error.log and tell me what error do you see there?

Comment: As weird as it may sound there is no error.log being outputted at all but I was able to noticed that once I type the URL it's as if it were redirecting to www. that's it, nothing after that.

Comment: First try from a different browser to avoid 301 caching issues. 2nd tell me for which URL are you getting `website unavailable` error?

Comment: Hey, I've been trying but there are so many redirect issues that it does not seem to be working after clicking two links, as an example. If I go to site.com/health/ then click on a header for home page it gives me this.. http://oddify.co/webroot/health/index.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php/ on the top it's not even redirecting site.co -> www.site.co . I've tried many different ways but none have seemed to work.. (hmmmmm).

Comment: Ok let me comment trailing slash rule since that seems to be culprit. Take complete code from edited answer and retest.

Comment: The trailing slash seemed to be the culprit yes. The only thing is that I have to hard link everything such adding full paths to everything but that's good nonetheless. Is there any way to add the slash rule back in there without having issues with the redirect? & I won't create another thread for this otherwise I'll figure it out myself as I've asked so much already, but possible to add hyphens to the article title, such as site.com/article/id/title-goes-here instead of site.com/article/title goes here with spaces. I should have mentioned it in the question but I forgot.

Comment: @AttisBarros: Let's get trailing slash rule working first then we'll work on replacing spaces with hyphens (that one is also not easy)

Comment: The only issue with the trailing slash is that it's adding a space at the end like site.com/about / instead of site.com/about/ . (I see, did not know)

Comment: Yes, I have tested the above code and it's working flawlessly. Should I add a new thread once again for the hyphens or is it fine here as it is?

Comment: Thanks and let me know link of the new question you create. I have started playing with that.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103413/friendly-urls-spaces-to-hyphens-uppercase-to-lowercase