# Friendly URLs spaces to hyphens & uppercase to lowercase

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'd like to convert spaces in dynamic URLs to use hyphens, and if there are any uppercase letters in the URL then it would make them lowercase.

### spaces to hyphens example

www.site.com/article/id/**title goes here** -> www.site.com/article/id/**title-goes-here**

### uppercase to lowercase example

www.site.com/article/id/**Title-Goes-Here** -> www.site.com/article/id/**title-goes-here**

My current .htaccess file rules.

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www before hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# if on article page, get slugs and make into friendly url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=302,NE]

# if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

# Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

# allow page direction to change the slugs into friendly seo URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# silently rewrite to webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# .php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have access to server config since case conversion would need a RewriteMap entry in Apache server config.

Comment: I do not, I am on shared hosting not VPS for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For space to hyphen conversion in your `/article/` URIs you can try this rule:

```
RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R]
```

**Insert this rule just above `Force a trailing slash` rule.**

**PS:** For case conversion you will need access to server config since case conversion would need a `RewriteMap` entry in Apache server config.

Comment: There seems to be an issue. I have an url with 16 works and 15 spaces in between them(tested with two urls), there was only one hyphen added but other URLs that are shorter seems to have worked. Also, is it possible to remove all characters from there URL such as commas, parenthesis and whatnot and only allow hyphens?

Comment: Probably, I'll check that part later. Is there anything to fix in the urls that have more length only adding one hyphen?

Comment: The article title is this Breather Aims To Launch Its Network Of On Demand Rooms In New York In Early 2014 and the output is this site.com/article/id/Breather Aims To Launch Its Network Of On-Demand Rooms In New York In Early 2014/

Comment: I'm trying to think here because I'm using a $_GET to retrieve the articles on the .php file so it get's the title and it's uid, but if I add the RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R] to it, the article cannot be found on the database anymore because I'm using $_GET and it's trying to find the articles with the hyphens on it it's not in the database. Hmm..

Comment: Yes, I'm a bit lost right now on what I should do to accomplish the hyphens but I'm unsure how to retrieve page content without the $_GET which I need so hmm.. well nonetheless the answer is correct, thank you.

Comment: That is actually what I am doing as you can see here, http://pastebin.com/74fbpZJR then retrieving the data with a query.

Comment: That's the issue, I cannot anub, if I add the following code RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R] the article content just gives blank space in the page meaning the $_GET isn't working (after I added the code you posted)

Comment: Accidentally deleted the comment again. I was able to make it work by only retrieving the information by using the article_uid, as I did not need the article_title for any reason so everything is working perfectly as of it. Thank you, do you have skype btw?

Comment: Hey, could you check this here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333203/why-is-google-indexing-friendly-url-mixed-with-hyphens-and-20/20334378?noredirect=1#comment30454880_20334378

Comment: Have you found anything?