# Why is Google indexing Friendly URL mixed with hyphens and %20?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-search

I developed a blog from scratch and things has gone great so far. I finally got around to writing my first post/article, and I've been waiting for Google to index this specific page to make sure there aren't any issue with it. Well, google is currently indexing the same page 4 times, I have (with the help of users from stackoverflow) a mod_rewrite on my htaccess to rewrite all urls to hyphens coming from a specific file (article.php).

My currently article page stands as followed. example:
`www.site.com/article.php?article_id=10&article_title=friendly url goes over here`

with mod_rewrite I have change the urls to the following.

`www.site.com/article/id/friendly-url-goes-over-here`

but Google seems to be indexing the same page 4 times like so..

```
www.site.com/article/10/friendly-url-goes-over-here
www.site.com/article/10/friendly-url-goes%20over%20here
www.site.com/article/10/friendly-url%20goes%20over%20here
www.site.com/article/10/friendly%20-url%20goes%20over%20here
```

Why is it indexing 4 of the same page? It seems to index the pages how many times each hyphen is inserted, so if there were 10 hyphens, I'm guessing Google would index 10 of the same page.. Here is all of my htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www before hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oddify\.co$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# if on article page, get slugs and make into friendly url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=302,NE]

# if page with .php is requested then remove the extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R]

# Force a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+?[^/.])[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=302,L]

# allow page direction to change the slugs into friendly seo URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (?:^|/)article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /webroot/article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# silently rewrite to webroot
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/webroot/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /webroot%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

# .php ext hiding
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

*I wrote this question a few days ago, I made sure to de-index the pages from google, then now google has gone ahead and re-indexed them the same way.*

Here is the google pages showing the 4 index pages: [google search page](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3awww.oddify.co&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this redirect to a 301:

```
RewriteRule "^(article)/([^ ]*) +(.*)$" /$1/$2-$3 [L,R=301]
```

The 301 status tells google (and browser and other clients) that the redirect is permanent and the old URL (the one with spaces) shouldn't be considered anymore.

Comment: I've been waiting for a few days(2) now just to make sure, but by adding the following, google does not seem to index the pages anymore, weird enough. I will leave it for a few days just to make sure.

Comment: Jon, it appears that now google does not index any pages after editing to your code. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @AttisBarros no idea why, maybe try submitting a sitemap?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your .htaccess file is that for every space in the title, it will do one redirect. It might or might not be fixed by using a permanent redirect (`301`), but even then browser will give an error (redirect loop detected) if too many spaces appear in the title. You can fix both problems by simply doing it all on the server:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^\ ]*)\ ([^\ ]*\ .*) /article/$1-$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^article/([^\ ]*)\ ([^\ ]*)$ /article/$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

The first rule matches if at least 2 spaces appear in the url, and will rewrite one of the spaces and order Apache to go through the `.htaccess` file again (`[N]`). If only one space is left, the second rule will match and, besides rewriting that last space, it will also redirect the user. This will only be one redirect, and hopefully the permanent redirect will cause only the new url to be visible in Google.

If there are more spaces in the url than there are internal recursions allowed by Apache, this will result in an Internal Server error. If you have access to `httpd.conf`, you can alter `LimitInternalRecursion` to allow more internal recursions. **Warning:** Set this to a SANE number. If, for some reason you have an endless loop in your RewriteRules and this number is insanely high, you'll lock up your server until it hits this limit. See [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitinternalrecursion).

Comment: I've been wanting for a few days(2) just to double check, I am testing Jon Lin's answer first as it was shorter but I will get to yours soon enough, thank you for answering overall.

Comment: Just an update, doing a 301 redirect did not fix the issue as (weird enough) google is no longer indexing pages coming from /article/.

Comment: Weird. What does [Google's Webmaster Dashboard](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) say?

Comment: Well recetly after I sybmited a sitemap I got a warning that says I should only insert links that don't redirect once reaching the page but of course that's from the re-writing to hyphens, other than that nothing at all.

Comment: Only glitch with this is it can cause `LimitInternalRecursion with 500 internal error` if there are more than 11 spaces in URI e.g. this URL: `/article/10/0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9http://localhost/article/10/0%201%202%203%204%205%206%207%208%209%20a%20b%20c`

Comment: @anubhava That's only by default, and unlike the browser at the client-side, you can configure Apache to allow more internal recursion. I'll add something about that to my answer.

Comment: Yes but that requires changing the Apache config and sometime folks on shared hosting aren't allowed to do that.

Comment: I see. Quickly tested the amount of redirects for browsers (per OP's and Jon Lin's solution) and it seems that Chrome, FireFox and Opera allow a maximum redirect chain of 20, and Safari allows a maximum redirect chain of 15. Internet explorer refuses to cooperate altogether (no clue why) and throws a 404 without redirecting at all. It might not have a maximum amount of hops in a redirect chain or just decided to be buggy. Even though a redirect chain allows for more spaces to be rewritten, I consider this a better solution over a redirect chain.

Comment: Yes I agree that if there is no realistic case of having dozen+ spaces in URI then this is better solution. +1

Comment: Thank you both for your solution, it seems that this is a better suited option overall as explained by both of your solutions. Only one quick resolution, the above code does not add in hyphens into the article title, any clue why?

Comment: @AttisBarros I am not sure what you mean. If I look at your site, you seem to have Jon Lin's solution in your .htaccess currently.

Comment: @Sumurai8, I know I left it in case google ramdomly does a check and somehow updates the website, but I have switched it so you can see. Check this article out and you'll see that with your solution does not include hyphens but just spaces. http://www.oddify.co/article/100/Fastest%20Way%20to%20Lose%20Weight%20For%20Men/

Comment: http://www.oddify.co/article/100/ returns an internal server error. I am assuming you placed it under a conflicting rule. Try moving my rule above the other rules.

Comment: No you see, I placed the whole url location in there but it replaced it with three dots in the end. Go here http://www.oddify.co/ and then click on the first article, you will see what I mean, there are no hyphens added into the article title anymore after changing to your code.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I was able to make the hyphens work by editing the code to the following, would you consider this to be correct still? http://pastebin.com/mntHZVjY

Comment: UPDATE: with the following code above I get the same redirect.. http://pastebin.com/cfubgB38 after I tried Jon lins code again it seemed to take all the redirects away.. I will wait a few days again before even posting anything.

Comment: That's because the first rule doesn't match anymore after your change. There is still an escaped space at the end of your first rewrite.